# ng-if is not working in ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and tried to make the spinner visible and invisible using $scope.status. I set the status value in ng-change function. It works for the first line of code, but when it comes to make it invisible, $scope.status updated but HTML didn't hide the spinner.

**Controller**

```
angular.module('starter')
  .controller('controller',['$scope','myService',myCtrl]);

function myCtrl($scope,myService){
   var newFunc = function(callback){
       myService.update(function(result){
          console.log("Calling service..."); /* Is calling each time I reload the page */
          result == true ? callback(true) : callback(false);
       });
   };

   $scope.onChangeCode = function(){
      console.log("onChanging...");
      $scope.status = true;
      newFunc(function(result){
         $scope.status = false; /* Status set to false, BUT HTML didn't update, spinner still showing*/
      });
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span ng-if="status == true">
    <ion-spinner  icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>
</span>
<input ng-model="code" ng-change="onChangeCode()"/>
```

**Problem**

> ng-if=true works well for making spinner visible, but it didn't hide spinner when ng-if=false within ng-change.

Comment: The function is "calling each time you reload" *while you define it*?! I think you need to provide more real code in order to determine what's going on here…

Comment: please provide more details such as input type and further code details.

Comment: @SanketTarodekar Updated.

Answer (score 0):

> in your code you missing ngModel, the ngChange need ngModel to bind because ngModel is required

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
$scope.checkIt = function() {
  console.log("here")
}
})
```

```html
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
  <input ng-model="me" ng-change="checkIt()">
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is not regarding to that calling function anymore. Right now, the ng-if is not working properly within ng-change.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you shown us, I don't think it will call `myService.update` each time you refresh it. May be you might need to add how `myService` look like

And do you really need `newFunc`? that part make it confusing
I think you can probably do something like

```
$scope.onChangeCode = function(){
    console.log("onChanging...");
    $scope.status = true;
    myService.update(function(result){
        $scope.status = result
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the value is changed the view does not got updated because of the callback I suppose. Use `$scope.$apply();` after you update the status;

https://embed.plnkr.co/t191Ed4bAcgbqkkTIIZV/

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`. The `ng-if` directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an expression. The `ng-show` directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the `ng-show` attribute. And you could use `ng-show="status"` it would work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I added  $scope.status = false; in top of controller.
and  $scope.$apply(); after update status;

Maybe this work

```
angular.module('starter')
  .controller('controller',['$scope','myService',myCtrl]);

function myCtrl($scope,myService){
     $scope.status = false;//Added this line
   var newFunc = function(callback){
       myService.update(function(result){
          console.log("Calling service..."); /* Is calling each time I reload the page */
          result == true ? callback(true) : callback(false);
       });
   };

   $scope.onChangeCode = function(){
      console.log("onChanging...");
      $scope.status = true;
      newFunc(function(result){
         $scope.status = false; 
      $scope.$apply(); //Added this line
      });
   }
}
```